# Convert an IEnumerable<T> to a list and then use the Contains method

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

To use the Contains method, I convert the `IEnumerable<T>` to a list with `ToList()` and then use the `Contains()` method, but it seems like it wants me to implement one myself. I also included the namespace `System.Collections.Generic`. Basically, I have a class like this:

```
class BookServices(){
   public int ID{ get; set; }
   public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

and the LoadAll() method like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<Books> LoadAll(){}
```

I just want to check if a certain ID exists in the IEnumerable or not then use that element with the Name property to do something with it

Here is what I did:

```
   var books= BookServices.LoadAll().ToList();
   var book= books.Where(stringtoCheck => stringtoCheck.Contains(id)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Edit: Visual Studio throws an error `throw new NotImplementedException()` although I assume that the `Contains` method is pre-implemented

Edit2: So BookServices is a data model class from Silverlight (correct me if what I call it is wrong here). It will returns an IEnumerable array, which is mainly for JSON request

Comment: no need to convert it to a list! that pulls everything where its not needed.

Comment: LoadAll() what does it return?

Comment: @Sajeetharan: An IEnumerable<T>

Comment: what is BookServices? If that's a dictionary then there is no need to do the ToList(). We really need more information to give you better answers... Right now we're all firing blindly trying to guess what the overall problem looks like

Comment: @DanielA.White if I don't convert it to a list is there other way that I could check the elements in the type and then iterate through it? I'm still learning about LINQ and C# so go ahead if you have something better to show :)

Comment: Wait, is a book a string? If not, you're calling `Book.Contains()`, not `string.Contains()` Maybe try `books.Where(book => book.Title.Contains(id))` Either way, I don't think you're doing what you think you're doing, and we don't know what you want to be doing, so we can't truly help you do it.

Comment: @Lynn read up on deferred vs. non-deferred link operators.

Comment: @Lynn... See? None of us know how to help you better because we're in the dark :P You can edit the original post. I would suggest copy/pasting and trimming it down to a "working" example that we can see. We can probably point you to a very efficient answer quickly that way :)

Comment: So BookServices.LoadAll() returns an arraylist? I think you can just use LINQ extensions off that then
Edit: I'm not the greatest at LINQ either but I think you could tack your lambda expression right after the LoadAll() but I could be wrong.

Comment: @alykins: Sorry I just corrected myself in the post. My bad

Comment: @Lynn, Please answer Magus's question. That seems like the most likely source of your problem.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: No. it isn't simply just a string. I updated my post to add more details

Comment: You might want to include the members of the `Books` class, since you want to operate on instances of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Book` is not a `String` so you don't get to use functions like `Contains`.

Using types instead of variable names to illustrate, your code looks like:

```
books.Where(Book => Book.Contains(id)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Clearly that isn't going to work!

If you are searching for a specific ID, your code would instead look like:

```
books.Where(book => book.ID == id)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Note that for performance reasons, you shouldn't use `Where` here. Just pass the predicate to `FirstOrDefault`:

```
books.FirstOrDefault(book => book.ID == id);
```

The reason this is important is `Where` will iterate the whole collection no matter what, whereas `FirstOrDefault` will stop when it finds a matching element.

**Actually, there is an optimization for `FirstOrDefault` that makes the two statements equivalent. This happens because `FirstOrDefault` only iterates the `Where` query until it finds a match.** It is still important to not use `Where` when you don't need to iterate the whole thing in general though.

Comment: Where does not iterate the whole thing.

Comment: @CSharpie Sure it does, how else would it find *every* matching element? A good portion of the LINQ queries do not short-circuit. Knowing which do can be very important when iterating can take a long time (like on `EnumerateFiles`).

Comment: It sure doesnt, see this simple fiddle to prove it: https://dotnetfiddle.net/q7TAKa

Comment: @CSharpie Thats an optimization from `FirstOrDefault` (which I didn't know it would do, so I'll edit to include it). If you change your first line to: `List<string> list = test().Where(s=> s == "B").ToList();` you will see it does indeed iterate the whole thing.

Comment: Yeah but this is because you removed the FirstOrDefault, this means it has to. FirstOrDefault is different to 'give me all items that match the condition'
Where is just a "filter", you decide wherether you stop at a certain point or let it filter the whole thing. By default Where is lazy, so you are still wrong here.

Comment: @CSharpie, hence my edit to that effect (noting this optimization). When I write LINQ, I assume that each query will run to completion no matter what comes after it. At the very least, this method of programming is less prone to mistakes. Without testing, I would *never* assume that these kind of optimizations will happen for you (lazy or not, iterations can still happen without you noticing if you are not careful).

Comment: Some functions dont accept a Lambda. e.g. Take. If you need the first 2 ... Still you are right, and I see your point.

If the method provides a way to define a predicate, use this instead of where.

Comment: @CSharpie Sure. I was mostly just trying to point out that `Where` can be very dangerous as people don't understand that it will iterate over the whole thing given the chance. I actually ran into this mistake with someone who has programmed C# for years. I apologize for the confusion. If you feel that my explanation of this could be better than I could come up with, I would happily accept an edit.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote this part here:

```
books.Where(stringtoCheck => stringtoCheck.Contains(id)).FirstOrDefault();
```

This means:

stringToCheck is of type Book

maybe you want to write something like this:

```
books.Where(b => stringtoCheck.Contains(b.Id)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Assuming your class Book has a property called Id of type String.

Also this can be further simplified by merging the Where-Lambda into the FirstOrDefault like this:

```
books.FirstOrDefault(b => stringtoCheck.Contains(b.Id));
```